# Do we only need the RouterModule when we define routes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-material

The [component-category-list](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/component-category-list/component-category-list.ts) of the Angular Material Documentation center imports the `RouterModule` but does not define any routes or reexport the `RouterModule`.

Does it need to import that `RouterModule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the [template](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/component-category-list/component-category-list.html) is using the `[routerLink]` directive and this comes from the RouterModule.

For more info see https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#directives.